# yii2 batch insert with utf-8 encoding

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2

i want to save multi record in database that has persian characters. i try this:

```
$actionArray = [
        [1,'تست1'],
        [2,'تست2'],
        [3,'تست3'],
        [4,'تست4'],
        [5,'تست5'],           
    ];

    \Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert("acc_actions",['act_id','act_name'],$actionArray)->execute();
```

but when it runs will save '????1' in table!
is there any way to pass utf-8 to batch insert or i must insert one by one into table?

Comment: first check if your database is set to utf8, make sure the connection is running over utf8 then try again, `'charset' => 'utf8',
        'initSQLs'=>'SET NAMES utf8;'`

Comment: i add this propery but yii2 show this error: Setting unknown property: yii\db\Connection::initSQLs

Comment: Does it work if you insert it one by one? Please edit your question to include your database configuration.

Comment: yes, when i insert records one by one it works.